# Better for SEO?

Tags: mobile, seo

Is it better for SEO to have a responsive website or a mobile only website with a computer website too. Is this

```
http://www.example.com/m
```

better or this

```
http://www.example.com/
```

for mobile and computer better.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO


Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either use two distinct mobile / desktop css files, or use media queries to detect the resolution (or mobile device) and style it accordingly. It's up to you to choose whichever you want (I'd go with media queries as it requires less coding). It's not a best practice to use example.com/m for example for the mobile version, and it will take longer to index that /m by search engines as well.

So, it's safe to use one of the two methods above. Either detect the resolution and device and serve a different css file, or use media queries. A great example of usage is covered here: http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Answer (score 0):

You could have both url's that will not considered in the SEO part. The important thing is to maintain the same SEF (Search Engine Friendly) Url's, title and Meta Description for mobile and desktop sites.

If you are going to have mobile site with sub-domain, that should be highly Responsive (all page) in nature and try to keep that page load faster than desktop site (Remove unnecessary widgets ). Highlight core features.

I hope this will help you.